# リネームしたファイルのリネーム前のコミットログが見たいのですが

Tags: git, github

「ここ書き換えたのどのタイミングだっけ？」となり、
GitHubでそのファイルのHistoryを見に行きました。
そのファイルは以前リネームしており、
私が見たかったコミットはリネーム前のに行っていたものだったようで、
そこには表示されていませんでした。

例えばGitHubでリネーム時のコミットへ行き、
そこから全体のHistoryを見てリネーム前のコミットへ行った後に該当のファイルを開いて
そのHistoryを見るということをすればリネーム前のコミットログを見ることができますが、
いちいちそのようなことをするのは不便だと感じています。

調べていて以下のgitコマンドを入力すれば
リネーム前のコミットログも一緒に見れることはわかりましたが、
GitHubでリネーム前のコミットログも一緒に見ることはできないのでしょうか？

```
git log --follow ファイルパス
```

Answer (score 2):

Qiitaに手順を載せました。
http://qiita.com/7of9/items/1984f3857672a10821f0

前提として「rename直後のコミットがわかる」のがあります。

手順は以下です
1. リポジトリに移動 [github](https://github.com/yasokada/150903-renamedFileFollow)
2. ファイル名 ( renamed.txt )をクリック
3. Blameをクリック
4. renameする直前のコミットをクリック (add 3Test)
5. Viewをクリック
6. Histroyをクリック

結構クリックが多いので、もっと楽な方法があればいいですね。

Comment: ここのコメントは読みづらくなると思ったのでQiitaの方にコメントさせてもらいました。
回答&記事投稿ありがとうございます。